# Tab content with next & privious options

Tags: php, jquery

```html
<script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/TabStylesInspiration/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<link href="http://tympanus.net/Development/TabStylesInspiration/css/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://tympanus.net/Development/TabStylesInspiration/css/tabstyles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section>
 <div class="tabs tabs-style-line">

  <div class="content-wrap">
   <a href="javascript(0);" class="prev">
    <img src="http://demo.litextension.com/le_demo/skin/frontend/default/default/le_itemslider/images/icon-prev.png">
   </a>

   <a href="javascript(0);" class="next">
    <img src="http://demo.litextension.com/le_demo/skin/frontend/default/default/le_itemslider/images/icon-next.png">
   </a>

   <section id="section-line-1"><p>1</p></section>
   <section id="section-line-2"><p>2</p></section>
   <section id="section-line-3"><p>3</p></section>
   <section id="section-line-4"><p>4</p></section>
   <section id="section-line-5"><p>5</p></section>
  </div><!-- /content -->

  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#section-line-1"><span>Our Controls</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-line-2"><span>Sony Playstation 4</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-line-3"><span>Microsoft Xbox One</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-line-4"><span>Nintendo Wii U</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-line-5"><span>Microconsoles</span></a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div><!-- /tabs -->
</section>

<script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/TabStylesInspiration/js/cbpFWTabs.js"></script>
<script>
 (function() {

  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tabs')).forEach(function(el) {
   new CBPFWTabs(el);
  });

 })();
</script>
```

[Tab Styles Inspiration](http://tympanus.net/Development/TabStylesInspiration/)

> Tab content work fine but how to add next previous option on this
>   inspiration.

[image]

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far and what are you expecting from us? Any chance to show us any code, maybe in a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Show us some more effort on this and we will hopefully provide ours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/bpzat7r0/3/

Pay attention to add ID attribute for div (.tabs) and nav link (.prev and .next)

**HTML:**

```
<section>
    <div class="tabs tabs-style-line" id="tab1">

        <div class="content-wrap">
            <a href="javascript:" class="prev" id="prev1">
                <img src="http://demo.litextension.com/le_demo/skin/frontend/default/default/le_itemslider/images/icon-prev.png">
            </a>

            <a href="javascript:" class="next" id="next1">
                <img src="http://demo.litextension.com/le_demo/skin/frontend/default/default/le_itemslider/images/icon-next.png">
            </a>

            <section id="section-line-1"><p>1</p></section>
            <section id="section-line-2"><p>2</p></section>
            <section id="section-line-3"><p>3</p></section>
            <section id="section-line-4"><p>4</p></section>
            <section id="section-line-5"><p>5</p></section>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#section-line-1"><span>Our Controls</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-line-2"><span>Sony Playstation 4</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-line-3"><span>Microsoft Xbox One</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-line-4"><span>Nintendo Wii U</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-line-5"><span>Microconsoles</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div><!-- /tabs -->
</section>
```

**JAVASCRIPT EDIT:**

```
 var $t=new CBPFWTabs(document.getElementById( 'tab1' ) )


document.getElementById('prev1').onclick=function(){

    var current=$t.current;
    var count=$t.items.length;

    current--;

    if(current<0) current=count-1;

    $t._show(current);

};

document.getElementById('next1').onclick=function(){

    var current=$t.current;
    var count=$t.items.length;

    current++;

    if(current>=count) current=0;

    $t._show(current);
};
```

Comment: this working very well but when i come on last tab so how to circular this one or hide.

Comment: check JAVASCRIPT EDIT abow

Comment: this is pure javascript

Comment: hiii i want a fade effect please where to add

Comment: for what you want to add effect? and when to start the animation?